# making a mobile friendly checkout nav

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am learning responsive design but I am stuck on making a chunk of css responsive. It is a checkout navigation that I would like list items to stack up. Below is the code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lt38hy9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkout-wrap">
  <ul class="checkout-bar" style="text-decoration:none">
    <li class="visited"><a style="text-decoration:none !important" href="">Step 1</a></li>
    <li class="last">Setp 2</li>
    <li class="last active">Setp 3</li>
    <li class="last">Setp 4</li>
    <li class="last">Setp 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkout-wrap {
      color: #444;
      font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
      margin: 40px auto;
      /*max-width: 1200px;*/
      position: relative;
    }

    ul.checkout-bar li {
      color: #ccc;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      position: relative;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:before {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      background: #ddd;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 700;
      left: 15px;
      line-height: 37px;
      height: 35px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      top: 4px;
      width: 20px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li.active {
      color: #77AA4E;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration:none !important;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li.active:before {
      background: #77AA4E;
      z-index: 99999;
      text-decoration:none !important;
    }

    ul.checkout-bar li.next {
        background:#ccc;
        font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration:none !important;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li.next:before {
        background:#ccc;
        z-index: 99999;
        text-decoration:none !important;
    }
    /*ul.checkout-bar li.next:after {
        background:#ccc;
    }*/

    ul.checkout-bar li.visited {
      background: #ECECEC;
      color: #57aed1;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li.visited:before {
      background: #57aed1;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(1):before {
      content: "1";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(2):before {
      content: "2";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(3):before {
      content: "3";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(4):before {
      content: "4";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(5):before {
      content: "5";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(6):before {
      content: "6";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(7):before {
      content: "7";
    }
     ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(8):before {
      content: "8";
    }
      ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(9):before {
      content: "9";
    }
    ul.checkout-bar a {
      color: #57aed1;
      font-size: 14px;
      /*font-weight: 600;*/
      text-decoration: none  !important;
    }
```

How can I go about making it mobile friendly? Any suggestions are appreciated. I am reading some articles but the ones I have tried have not yielded anything yet.

Comment: Use viewports to make your website appear differently when the window size changes or when it is accessed from devices that use smaller screens.

Comment: I have already done that.

Comment: @FlipFloop bootstrap is not the answer for everything...

Comment: You fiddle looks funny... why?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith that is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Then how do you want it to look? because it looks bad in full screen too.

Comment: @mpora in that case you can implement a dropdown list or a hamburger icon in your design.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I would like it to stack up. So the number in the circle on the left and the text on the right. I got it from this website: http://designscrazed.org/jquery-css3-progress-bars/. In my full website, it looks ok on desktop.

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga hamburger icon is already being used for the main menu. This checkout menu I am working on is a sub menu.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at this: http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/LELBEo